# Как спарсить сайт?

Tags: php, парсер

Привет!
Есть сайт www.stillini.ru
Работает он очень странно, если пытаемся получить его контент (file_get_contents или curl), он возвращает такие заголовки:
http://domw.net/service:network-http_headers#l:http_headers:data:www.stillini.ru

Вопрос: как получить html код этого сайта на php?

Comment: "html код этого сайта на php" - да уж...

Answer (score 1):

годится для отдельных страниц, если скачивать со связанными файлами, авторизация и проч, лучше использовать что-то более...

1. Убеждаемся, что нашли, скачали и положили в каталог для экспериментов curl.exe
2. Запускаем инструменты разработчика (Chrome), в них вкладка network/сеть. Заходим на страницу, в инструментах правый клик на запрошенной странице, в случае с Win "Copy as Curl (cmd)" - получаем полнейший набор параметров для curl, вставляем в промежуточный *.cmd файл, запускаем, убеждаемся что страница скачивается (лучше из командной строки или добавить "pause" последней строкой файла)
3. Изучаем -H параметры, удаляя (комментируя?) по очереди. Как перестанет скачивать, значит удалили лишний заголовок :)

Ключевыми скорей всего будут (на примере текущей страницы):
-H "Origin: http://ru.stackoverflow.com"
-H "X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest"
-H "Cookie: ..."
-H "Referer: ..."
Как получили минимальный набор параметров, при котором страница еще скачивается, переходим к программированию собственно функции

4. За основу взять http://php.net/manual/ru/function.curl-exec.php, в одном из первых комментарием просто замечательная функция, дополнить разве что - заголовки передавать с опцией CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, а для Cookie отдельный параметр CURLOPT_COOKIE

пользуйтесь

Answer (score 0):

Я так понимаю file_get_contents его не читает, а в браузере обычном он открывается. Тогда нужно эмулировать работу браузера через curl. Есть хороший класс уже для этого: http://habrahabr.ru/post/114226/